# Set of coefficients such that polynomial has real zeros is closed

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show that the set of coefficients $(a_0,\ldots,a_{d-1})\in\mathbb C^d$ such that $a_0+a_1z+\cdots+a_{d-1}z^{d-1}+z^d$ only has real zeros, is closed.

I would like to present some kind of approach by myself but I can't see at all which theorems/methods would give me such results.

Comment: You can try to prove that the complement of this set is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that the complement is open.  If $p(z)$ has some non-real zero, take a circle around one such zero that doesn't intersect the real line and doesn't have any zeros on it.  By [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem), any polynomial with coefficients sufficiently close to those of $p$ also has a zero inside the circle, and thus at least one non-real zero.

Comment: (+1) Clear and concise. Maybe it might be useful to add a link to the statement/proof of Rouché theorem.

Comment: Link added for those who don't know how to use Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Show that the complement is open.
If $\alpha\in\Bbb C\setminus \Bbb R$ is a root of $a_0+a_1z+\ldots +z^d$ then any polynomial $b_0+b_1z+\ldots +z^d$ with only real roots is "far away": Write 
$b_0+b_1z+\ldots +z^d=(z-\beta_1)\cdots(z-\beta_d)$ with $\beta_j\in\Bbb R$. Then $b_0+b_1z+\ldots +z^d$ evaluated at $\alpha$ is $\prod(\alpha-\beta_j)$ and this is at least $|\operatorname{Im}(\alpha)|^d$ in absolute value.